# yyyymmddhhmmss to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, date

What is the best way to convert yyyymmddhhmmss to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and back in perl?

for example: 20130218165601 to 2013-02-18 16:56:01 and back?
(can https://metacpan.org/module/Rose::DateTime do it)?

without regexp, if possible ;)

Comment: ...while standing on one leg and having one hand behind the back? Why not regex?

Comment: I think it is too simple. and how about validation?

Comment: "too simple"? You like things complicated? What about validation? You mean validate that it is a proper date?

Comment: Do you want the code to convert, or convert and validate? You only asked for the the former, but you're now implying you want the latter. If it's the latter, how thorough do you want to be? Just a simple length check, or do you want to validate leap days? leap seconds?

Comment: Thanx for all. I think strptime (DateTime::Format::Strptime) is the best solution for me :) I have just registered here and I am surprised how quickly I've got an answer!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A module is overkill for this.

```
# Packed -> ISO
(my $iso_date = $packed_date) =~
   s/^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\z/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6/s;

# ISO -> Packed
(my $packed_date = $iso_date) =~
   s/^(....)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..)\z/$1$2$3$4$5$6/s;
```

---

[Rose::DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rose::DateTime) cannot parse the "packed" format as intended, but you could use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime).

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
my $packed_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S',
   on_error => 'croak',
);
my $iso_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

# Packed -> ISO
my $iso_date = $iso_format->format_datetime(
   $packed_format->parse_datetime($packed_date)
);

# ISO -> Packed
my $packed_date = $packed_format->format_datetime(
   $iso_format->parse_datetime($iso_date)
);
```

Comment: Or `(my $packed_date = $iso_date) =~ s/\D//g ;` if `$iso_date` contains nothing else.

Comment: @dgw, True. I went with what I posted out of habit since it can handle changes in the order of the fields, something I commonly need. Furthermore, it performs a modicum of validation. Finally, the intent of the code I posted is crystal clear, and I like the symmetry between the two conversions.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI ... but symmetry and validation are certainly a nice bonus.

Comment: Thanx. DateTime::Format::Strptime maybe is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Quick solution with `sprintf`.

```
my $date = sprintf "%s%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", $string =~ /(..)/g;
```

And back:

```
my $foo = join '', $date =~ /\d+/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

without regular expressions, you can just use `substr` to grab the characters you want:

```
$year  = substr $d, 0, 4;
$month = substr $d, 4, 2;
...
$secs  = substr $d, 12, 2;
```