# Date time transform in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [yyyymmddhhmmss to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203153/yyyymmddhhmmss-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-perl)

I have a datetime from user `2012/02/10 00:00:00`, and want to change it to`2012-02-10 00:00:00`, I know regex can do this. Is there any module can do this?

Comment: -1 for saying the code has to be in a module instead of saying what problems a regex solution has.

Comment: -1: your question has seemingly arbitrary (i.e. unexplained) restrictions. klortho #11903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module is overkill for this.

```
(my $iso_date = $slashed_date) =~
   s{^(....)/(..)/(..) (..:..:..)\z}{$1-$2-$3 $4}s;
```

But here's one if you want one:

```
package My::Date::Converter;

use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( date_converter );

sub date_converter {
   my ($slashed_date) = @_;
   (my $iso_date = $slashed_date) =~
       s{^(....)/(..)/(..) (..:..:..)\z}{$1-$2-$3 $4}s;
   return $iso_date;
}

1;
```

But if you feel like wasting a lot of CPU, there are existing modules that can do this:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $slashed_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $iso_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $iso_date = $iso_format->format_datetime(
   $slashed_format->parse_datetime($slashed_date)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

use `tr`:

```
perl -le '$_="2012/02/10 00:00:00";tr|/|-|;print'
```